# Java - Conflicting interface type parameters

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that involves reading in structures from a string/stream.
As part of my design I attempted to create something along these lines:

- `public class Thing;`
- `public class SpecialThing extends Thing;`
- `public class ShinyThing extends Thing;`
- `public abstract class ThingDeserialiser implements Iterable<Thing>;`
- `public abstract class GenericThingDeserialiser<T extends Thing> extends ThingDeserialiser implements Iterable<T>;`
- `public class SpecialThingDeserialiser extends GenericThingDeserialiser<SpecialThing>;`
- `public class ShinyThingDeserialiser extends GenericThingDeserialiser<ShinyThing>;`

However I get an error with `GenericThingDeserialiser` because there is a conflict between

- `ThingDeserialiser` implementing `Iterable<Thing>` and
- `GenericThingDeserialiser` trying to implement `Iterable<T>`.

I am able to create a set up like this in `C#`, why am I unable to do this in `Java`?

Is there a way around this somehow?

---

I have also considered removing `ThingDeserialiser` in hope that `ShinyThingDeserialiser` and `SpecialThingDeserialiser` might both be castable to `GenericThingDeserialiser<Thing>`, but as expected that's not going to work.

I have another idea involving interfaces, but I'd like to stop and ask for advice before continuing.

If it's not obvious, the general idea is that the `Thing` objects are retrieved from strings/streams based on reasonably trivial patterns.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas My main reason for attempting things the way I have is that I'm more experienced with C# and things like that work in C#, so I'm used to things like this working. My main reason for having a `ThingDeserialiser` at the top is so I could have a collection of `ThingDeserialiser`s that could be any form of `GenericThingDeserialiser` or anything lower down the chain. Additionally it would be possible to extend `ThingDeserialiser` and not the generic version for niche cases such as wrapping a factory that could generate `ShinyThing` or `SpecialThing`. Long story short: flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely suggest removing ThingDeserialiser. You say you want to cast ShinyThingDeserialiser and SpecialThingDeserializer to GenericThingDeserialiser<Thing>, but that won't work. You should be able to cast them to GenericThingDeserialiser<? extends Thing>. Does that help?

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot about wildcards. Thank you for reminding me that they exist.

Answer (score 4):

> I am able to create a set up like this in C#, why am I unable to do this in Java?

Because generics in Java are not covariant.

That is, even if you have types `A` and `B`, and `B` extends `A`, class `Foo<B>` will not be a subtype of `Foo<A>`. Due to type erasure, at runtime, both will be `Foo`.

As already suggested, you should really get rid of `ThingDeserialiser` here and just do with the `GenericThingDeserializer<T extends Thing> implements Iterable<T>`. You can then create, say, `MyThingDeserialiser implements GenericThingDeserialiser<MyThing>`.

Comment: "Because generics in Java are not covariant." That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I did accept this originally, but @David made an excellent point about wildcards and ideally I'd like to accept both, but since he's slightly lower on rep, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: Thats nice of you Pharap. As for fge, I upvoted your answer ;)

Comment: @DavidtenHove Probably goes against the site guidelines, but I've seen it done before. Again, I'd love to be able to accept both, but  it would probably take more effort than it would provide rewards.

Comment: I upvoted because the answer is good. Not because of the points.